# JPA does not persist children

Tags: java, database, jpa

Following scenario:

I have

user object:

```
...
@Column(name = "TITLE")
private String title;
@NotNull
@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "STREET_ADRESS")
private String streetAdress;
@NotNull
@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "CITY")
private String city;
```

...

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@NotNull
@NotEmpty
protected Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();

    Role roleDaoById = roleService.getRoleByName(RoleName.User.toString());
    Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    roles.add(roleDaoById);
    member.setRoles(roles);
    member.setSuspend(false);
    member.setPlayer(true);
memberService.addMember(member);
```

My problem is that roles are already available in the database. That's why i load them via roleService.
I call memberService.addMember and this calls my dao with em.persist(member). But this call does save the role again and i get a duplicate key error for the role object.
I only want to save the member and then make the join table entry for the role.

What can i do?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903800/hibernate-inserts-duplicates-into-a-onetomany-collection) help?

Comment: Thanx for your answer, but don't know how this could help me?

Comment: Specifically, can you try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7905027/248082)?

Comment: "When doing one of the following, the code works fine (no duplicate entries in the list):

    remove the mappedBy attribute in the parent entity  , "[...]->> but i dont have this attribute. i dont know why i should flush, because my user object is new and the role is already in the database

Comment: not enough reputation, so my solution is here: @ManyToMany solves my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relation User - Role is Many-To-Many (one user has multiple roles, multiple users can have the same role), but you annotated it with One-To-Many.