# Hibernate inserts duplicats - Very difficult to spot

Tags: hibernate, insert, duplicates

after several hours I have finally decided to post my problem, and see if anyone has had this problem before. This is very curious and I am not being able to spot the problem. I have a customer management system with the following entities:

BusinessUnit , Invoice, InvoiceItem, PictureFolder and Event

The relationships between them are as follows:

BusinessUnit--OtM-->InvoiceItem

BusinessUnit--OtM-->PictureFolder

BusinessUnit--OtM-->Event

Invoice--OtM-->InvoiceItem

InvoiceItem--MtO-->Event

PictureFolder--MtO-->Event

Event--Mto-->BusinessUnit

BusinessUnit is where all invoice items from one or severael invoices for a given businessunit go. Invoice, InvoiceItem and PictureFolder are hopefully selfexplanatory. Event serves us as an InvoiceItem holder for a given event (understanding that an event is anything that happens to a businessunit, such as any given repair to conduct). So an event may involve several invoice items corresponding to several BusinessUnits and Invoices.

Hope this model explanation is clear.

My problem is that when I persist an Invoice, where I have created one event (in the same usercase, saving it through a single persist() call to the Invoice object and relying on cascading features) the Event instance gets duplicated. The rest is written properly to the database (MySQL by the way).

The following are the weirdest results I have found:

At calling the persist method : persist(invoice) I make a comparison between the object passed to the method, and the resulting object of the call, say inv1 and inv2, being inv2 the resulting instance.

When checking the event instances for the BusinessUnit and BillableItem instances in inv1, the references point to the same object.

But when checking the same instance paths in the resulting instance inv2, two different instances are given back, which in turn corresponds to a ducplicate entry inserted in the MySQL 'events' table.

The ORM Mapping is done through annotations and are as follows:

### BusinessUnit

@OneToMany(mappedBy="businessUnit",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true) List events = new ArrayList();

### Invoice

@OneToMany(mappedBy="invoice",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true) List items= new ArrayList();

### InvoiceItem

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST) @JoinColumn(name="event_id") Event event;

### Event

@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="businessUnit_id") BusinessUnit businessUnit;

Actually the relationship between BusinessUnit and Event seems redundant, then the relationship can be indirectly obtained through the invoiceItem instances. That can probably solve the problem, because what is apparently causing the duplicate entry is the instance hold by the businessunit.

That can be a solution. But I am open to any other solutions.

All this was quite difficult for me to explain in detail. Hope the problem is clear.

Thanks for your time and best regards,

Carlos.

Comment: You say "an event may involve several invoice items corresponding to several BusinessUnits" - that implies to me a Many-to-Many relationship between Even and BusinessUnit, not Many-to-One.

Comment: Also just found this, may be the same : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903800/hibernate-inserts-duplicates-into-a-onetomany-collection

Comment: Sonds like a ManyToMany, however in between of those entities additional information needs to be supplied, that's why...

Comment: So do all of an event's InvoiceItems and PictureFolders always belong to the same BusinessUnit as the event?  And is there any relationship beyween the Invoice and the Business Unit (ie. can a single invoice have items belonging to many business units?)  If the answers to these are "yes", then it would be good practice to remove unnecessary foreign keys (and those could be contributing to the problem)

Comment: Perhaps you are right,... but removing those "unnecessary references" would impact significantly my code. At the end of the day it all comes down to have the same reference among different nodes in an object graph, and let those different nodes not create an additional table entry, for we are dealing with the same reference....