# Hibernate's PersistentSet not using custom implementations of hashCode/equals

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

So I have an entity Book

```
public class Book {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private String description;
  private Image coverImage;
  private Set<Chapter> chapters;

  //Sets & Gets

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Book)) return false;
    Book book = (Book) o;
    return Objects.equals(name, book.name) &&
            Objects.equals(description, book.description) &&
            Objects.equals(image, book.image) &&
            Objects.equals(chapters, book.chapters);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name, description, image, chapters);
  }
}
```

an entity Chapter

```
public class Chapter {
  private String id;
  private String title;
  private String number;
  private LocalDate releaseDate;
  private Set<Distributor> distributors;

  //Sets & Gets

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Chapter)) return false;
    Chapter chapter = (Chapter) o;
    return Objects.equals(title, chapter.title) &&
            Objects.equals(number, chapter.number) &&
            Objects.equals(releaseDate, chapter.releaseDate) &&
            Objects.equals(distributors, chapter.distributors);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(title, number, releaseDate, distributors);
  }
}
```

and a Distributor entity

```
public class Distributor {

  private String id;
  private String name;
  private Image logoImage;

  //Sets & Gets

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Distributor)) return false;
    Distributor that = (Distributor) o;
    return Objects.equals(name, that.name) &&
            Objects.equals(logoImage, that.logoImage);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name, logoImage);
  }
}
```

I have a `List<Chapter>` of old and new chapters and I have to add only the new ones to the Book. 
Hibernate fetches and populates the `Set<Chapter>` with all the chapters in the database using its custom implementation `PersistentSet`.

The problem I'm trying to solve is add only those chapters from the List that are not present in the PersistentSet. For this I though, as Chapter does not uses the id field to calculate the hashCode/equals I could just add all the chapters from the List to the PersistentSet and the result should be a Set that excluded those from the list that already exists and included those that are not in the set. Well... this is not happening.

Hibernate's `PersistentSet` is not using the hashCode/equals function I defined for the `Distributor` entity but some internal implementation of it, resulting in the Chapters from the List and Set having different hashCodes and been not equals. Lets call a chapter from the List `lChapter` and a chapter from the PersistentSet `psChapter` and assume they are equals except for the Id.
If I do

```
lChapter.equals(psChapter); //True
```

but If I do

```
psChapter.equals(lChapter); //False
```

And if I do

```
book.getChapters().addAll(chapters);
```

Being `book` an attached entity with 20 chapters and `chapters` the List with 21 chapters the result is a set with 41 chapters.

I'm I doing something wrong here? I find it been a very trivial problem yet I haven't found any solution that doesn't involves me going through the List and check if its contained before adding. Its an unnecessary extra step that I can't afford.

Edit 1: Image is a custom implementation and does implements hashCode/equals and already proved its not the problem. Even if I remove from the entities the above experiments results doesn't change.

Edit 2: I debugged the code and when doing `lChapter.equals(psChapter);` if you go into `Objects.equals(distributors, chapter.distributors)` of the Chapter's equals function, it goes to the Distributor equals function whereas on the `psChapter.equals(lChapter);` it goes into the PersistentSet one.

Comment: Does those new Chapter has same Distributors object ?

Comment: Yes, they are exactly the same. As I said, the only difference is the Id field. Edited the post to include information regarding it.

Comment: Are `lChapter` and `psChapter` instances of a `Chapter` or `List` and `Set` respectively?

Comment: Both are Chapter, both are equal. psChapter is populated from hibernate and lChapter is taken from the list. Both, the List and the Set contain mostly the same Chapters.
Like my example above. Lest say the List has 21 chapters, 20 out of the 21 chapters are already in the database but 1, yet IN THE LIST neither is an attached entity. On the other hand the set has 20 Chapters (the same 20 of the list, but this are attached entities in a PersistentSet). If you try to add all the Chapters in the list to the PersistentSet, you get 41 instead of 21. This is just an example.

Comment: This is bcos of the hibernate issue `PersistentSet does not honor hashcode/equals contract when loaded eagerly`. I have updated the answer with the details.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround for this issue is to add an `@OrderColumn` to the relationship between **Book** and **Chapter** like this:

```
public class Book {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private String description;
  private Image coverImage;
  @OrderColumn
  private Set<Chapter> chapters;
...
}
```

This will get rid of the `PersistentSet` and instead use the `PersistentSortedSet` of Hibernate which does not violate the equals/hashCode contract.

By the way I was wondering why you don't have any `@OneToMany` / `@ManyToMany` annotations? Seems Hibernate does it automatically (which I find creepy). How does Hibernate decide whether it's a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

After going through the hibernate JIRA [PersistentSet does not honor hashcode/equals contract when loaded eagerly](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3799)
 it is a known issue.

*The collection loaded eagerly in some situations calls hashcode on its items before their field values are populated and thus the other methods like contain(), remove() etc are impacted.*

The fix is planned for 6.0.0 Alpha.

And as per one of the suggestions in the JIRA as a workaround, *it's much better to stick to LAZY collections. EAGER fetching is bad for performance, can lead to Cartesian Products, and you can't paginate the collection.*

And that should explain why

`Chapter.equals(psChapter);` returns `true` since it uses normal Set.equals

`psChapter.equals(lChapter);` returns `false`.

This goes via PersistentSet while violates the hashcode/equals contract and thus it is not guaranteed to return true even if the element is present in the Set. And further it results in allowing adding duplicate elements to the Set as well.

Comment: Image is not the problem. Edited the post to add clarification over it. Thanks for the answer anyway :).

Comment: Also if it were the Image, it should've return false or true in both cases.

Comment: For this particular case Lazy loading would be a waste since I need all the data there anyways. And also, the entity is out of session context by the time I access the data so I'll get a Lazy initialization exception. Its funny how the ticket was created back in 2009 and its been 9 years and still theres no deploy of it.

Comment: That really came as a surprise to me. Hope that gets fixed in 6.0.0 Alpha.

Comment: To overcome the LazyInitializationException, using HQL with JOIN FETCH could be one approach. Again this is a work around.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with main method, and it is working as expected, as below

Could you please try with your code ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();

    Distributor db = new Distributor();
    db.setId("1");
    db.setLogoImage(null);
    db.setName("Name");
    Set<Distributor> dbs = new HashSet<>();
    dbs.add(db);

    Chapter c= new Chapter();
    c.setDistributors(dbs);
    c.setId("1");
    c.setNumber("123");
    c.setReleaseDate(now);
    c.setTitle("10:30");
    Set<Chapter> chapters = new HashSet<>();
    chapters.add(c);


    Book b= new Book();
    b.setChapters(chapters);
    b.setCoverImage(null);
    b.setDescription("Description");
    b.setId("1");
    b.setName("Name");


    Set<Distributor> dbs1 = new HashSet<>();
    Distributor db1 = new Distributor();
    db1.setId("1");
    db1.setLogoImage(null);
    db1.setName("Name");
    dbs1.add(db1);

    Chapter c1 = new Chapter();
    c1.setDistributors(dbs1);
    c1.setId("1");
    c1.setNumber("123");
    c1.setReleaseDate(now);
    c1.setTitle("10:30");

    System.out.println(chapters.add(c1));
    System.out.println(chapters.size());

}
```

Comment: I don't think you understood what the problem is. I don't see how your code its an example of what I'm doing or what I'm trying to solve. Thank you for the answer anyway :)

Comment: Last 2 lines shows that whatever hascode and equals method you wrote is correct, From hibernate perspective you need to publish whole code