# Hibernate @OneToMany mappedby inserts duplicate records when saved

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-onetomany

I'm working on a Java project using Spring Boot 2.6.6 and Spring Data JPA and Hibernate 5.6.7.Final.

and I'm getting a strange behaviour.

Consider following entities (getters and setters are omitted for brevity):

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "user")
  private List<ContactInfo> contactInfos = new ArrayList<>();
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "contact_info")
public class ContactInfo {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String phoneNumber;

  private String address;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "uid")
  private User user;

}
```

I have already saved the user in the database and want to add a ContactInfo to it.
I use Spring Data JPA and test is written with it.

```java
 @Transactional
  public User saveUser() {  saved the user in the database first
    User user = new User();
    user.setName("kevin");
    return userRepository.save(user);
  }
  

  @Transactional
  public User updateContactInfo(Long id) { // find user from db and add a ContactInfo to it.
    User user = userRepository.findById(id).get();
    ContactInfo contactInfo = new ContactInfo();
    contactInfo.setUser(user);
    user.getContactInfos().add(contactInfo);
    User saveUser = userRepository.save(user);
    System.out.println(saveUser.getContactInfos().size()); //2
    return user;
  }
```

After that hibernate perform Merge operation on User entity and Cascade merge on `contactInfos` collection. I expect that `saveUser` will have one element in `contactInfos` collection, but it contains two the same elements. In database created only one.

Below is a log of my execution:

```
2023-02-13 11:03:54.585  INFO 2016 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.7.Final
2023-02-13 11:03:54.815  INFO 2016 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2023-02-13 11:03:55.311  INFO 2016 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-02-13 11:03:55.631  INFO 2016 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-02-13 11:03:55.677  INFO 2016 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
Hibernate: 
    
    create table contact_info (
       id bigint generated by default as identity,
        address varchar(255),
        phone_number varchar(255),
        uid bigint,
        primary key (id)
    )
Hibernate: 
    
    create table user (
       id bigint generated by default as identity,
        name varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    )
2023-02-13 11:03:56.761  INFO 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-02-13 11:03:56.772  INFO 2016 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-02-13 11:03:56.943 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] tor$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler : Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation
2023-02-13 11:03:57.057 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] tor$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler : Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation
2023-02-13 11:03:57.166 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] tor$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler : Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation
2023-02-13 11:03:57.230 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] tor$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler : Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation
2023-02-13 11:03:57.232 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] tor$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler : Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation
2023-02-13 11:03:57.538  WARN 2016 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-02-13 11:03:58.660  INFO 2016 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2023-02-13 11:03:58.728  INFO 2016 --- [           main] org.example.service.UserTest             : Started UserTest in 6.785 seconds (JVM running for 8.934)
2023-02-13 11:03:58.959 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name [org.example.service.UserService.saveUser]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2023-02-13 11:03:58.959 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(367559104<open>)] for JPA transaction
2023-02-13 11:03:58.966 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@e594c46]
2023-02-13 11:03:58.982 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(367559104<open>)] for JPA transaction
2023-02-13 11:03:58.983 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Participating in existing transaction
2023-02-13 11:03:58.995 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.hibernate.event.internal.EntityState   : Transient instance of: org.example.entity.User
2023-02-13 11:03:58.996 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.DefaultPersistEventListener      : Saving transient instance
2023-02-13 11:03:59.001 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener        : Saving [org.example.entity.User#<null>]
2023-02-13 11:03:59.020 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.hibernate.event.internal.WrapVisitor   : Wrapped collection in role: org.example.entity.User.contactInfos
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        user
        (id, name) 
    values
        (default, ?)
2023-02-13 11:03:59.033 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [kevin]
2023-02-13 11:03:59.049 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction commit
2023-02-13 11:03:59.049 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(367559104<open>)]
2023-02-13 11:03:59.050 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushing session
2023-02-13 11:03:59.050 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Processing flush-time cascades
2023-02-13 11:03:59.051 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Dirty checking collections
2023-02-13 11:03:59.052 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushing entities and processing referenced collections
2023-02-13 11:03:59.058 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Processing unreferenced collections
2023-02-13 11:03:59.059 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Scheduling collection removes/(re)creates/updates
2023-02-13 11:03:59.062 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
2023-02-13 11:03:59.062 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushed: 1 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 1 collections
2023-02-13 11:03:59.063 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Executing flush
2023-02-13 11:03:59.066 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Post flush
2023-02-13 11:03:59.069 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(367559104<open>)] after transaction
2023-02-13 11:03:59.070 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name [org.example.service.UserService.updateContactInfo]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2023-02-13 11:03:59.070 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(1978865375<open>)] for JPA transaction
2023-02-13 11:03:59.071 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@2d4aadc]
2023-02-13 11:03:59.071 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(1978865375<open>)] for JPA transaction
2023-02-13 11:03:59.071 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Participating in existing transaction
2023-02-13 11:03:59.079 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : Loading entity: [org.example.entity.User#1]
2023-02-13 11:03:59.079 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : Attempting to resolve: [org.example.entity.User#1]
2023-02-13 11:03:59.081 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : Object not resolved in any cache: [org.example.entity.User#1]
Hibernate: 
    select
        user0_.id as id1_1_0_,
        user0_.name as name2_1_0_ 
    from
        user user0_ 
    where
        user0_.id=?
2023-02-13 11:03:59.086 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2023-02-13 11:03:59.098 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(1978865375<open>)] for JPA transaction
2023-02-13 11:03:59.098 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Participating in existing transaction
2023-02-13 11:03:59.099 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] h.e.i.EntityCopyObserverFactoryInitiator : Configured EntityCopyObserver strategy: disallow
2023-02-13 11:03:59.102 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.hibernate.event.internal.EntityState   : Persistent instance of: org.example.entity.User
2023-02-13 11:03:59.103 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.DefaultMergeEventListener        : Ignoring persistent instance
2023-02-13 11:03:59.104 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.hibernate.event.internal.EntityState   : Transient instance of: org.example.entity.ContactInfo
2023-02-13 11:03:59.105 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.DefaultMergeEventListener        : Merging transient instance
2023-02-13 11:03:59.105 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.DefaultMergeEventListener        : Already in merge process
2023-02-13 11:03:59.105 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener        : Saving [org.example.entity.ContactInfo#<null>]
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        contact_info
        (id, address, phone_number, uid) 
    values
        (default, ?, ?, ?)
2023-02-13 11:03:59.106 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2023-02-13 11:03:59.106 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2023-02-13 11:03:59.106 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2023-02-13 11:04:05.522 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener : Initializing collection [org.example.entity.User.contactInfos#1]
2023-02-13 11:04:05.523 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener : Checking second-level cache
2023-02-13 11:04:05.523 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener : Collection not cached
Hibernate: 
    select
        contactinf0_.uid as uid4_0_0_,
        contactinf0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        contactinf0_.id as id1_0_1_,
        contactinf0_.address as address2_0_1_,
        contactinf0_.phone_number as phone_nu3_0_1_,
        contactinf0_.uid as uid4_0_1_ 
    from
        contact_info contactinf0_ 
    where
        contactinf0_.uid=?
2023-02-13 11:04:05.524 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2023-02-13 11:04:05.530 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : Loading entity: [org.example.entity.ContactInfo#1]
2023-02-13 11:04:05.531 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : Attempting to resolve: [org.example.entity.ContactInfo#1]
2023-02-13 11:04:05.531 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener : Collection initialized
2
2023-02-13 11:04:36.584 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction commit
2023-02-13 11:04:36.585 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(1978865375<open>)]
2023-02-13 11:04:36.585 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushing session
2023-02-13 11:04:36.585 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Processing flush-time cascades
2023-02-13 11:04:36.586 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.hibernate.event.internal.EntityState   : Persistent instance of: org.example.entity.ContactInfo
2023-02-13 11:04:36.586 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.DefaultPersistEventListener      : Ignoring persistent instance
2023-02-13 11:04:36.586 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.hibernate.event.internal.EntityState   : Persistent instance of: org.example.entity.User
2023-02-13 11:04:36.586 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.DefaultPersistEventListener      : Ignoring persistent instance
2023-02-13 11:04:36.587 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.hibernate.event.internal.EntityState   : Persistent instance of: org.example.entity.ContactInfo
2023-02-13 11:04:36.587 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.DefaultPersistEventListener      : Ignoring persistent instance
2023-02-13 11:04:36.587 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.hibernate.event.internal.EntityState   : Persistent instance of: org.example.entity.ContactInfo
2023-02-13 11:04:36.587 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.DefaultPersistEventListener      : Ignoring persistent instance
2023-02-13 11:04:36.587 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.hibernate.event.internal.EntityState   : Persistent instance of: org.example.entity.ContactInfo
2023-02-13 11:04:36.587 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.DefaultPersistEventListener      : Ignoring persistent instance
2023-02-13 11:04:36.589 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.hibernate.event.internal.EntityState   : Persistent instance of: org.example.entity.User
2023-02-13 11:04:36.589 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.DefaultPersistEventListener      : Ignoring persistent instance
2023-02-13 11:04:36.589 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Dirty checking collections
2023-02-13 11:04:36.589 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushing entities and processing referenced collections
2023-02-13 11:04:36.589 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Processing unreferenced collections
2023-02-13 11:04:36.589 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Scheduling collection removes/(re)creates/updates
2023-02-13 11:04:36.590 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 2 objects
2023-02-13 11:04:36.591 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 1 updates, 0 removals to 1 collections
2023-02-13 11:04:36.591 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Executing flush
2023-02-13 11:04:36.593 TRACE 2016 --- [           main] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Post flush
2023-02-13 11:04:36.594 DEBUG 2016 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(1978865375<open>)] after transaction
2023-02-13 11:04:36.624  INFO 2016 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-02-13 11:04:36.628  INFO 2016 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-02-13 11:04:36.654  INFO 2016 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

I found that other people had raised the same question, but it still didn't seem to be solved. The following links are for reference.

- [Hibernate inserts duplicates into a @OneToMany collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903800/hibernate-inserts-duplicates-into-a-onetomany-collection)
- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14078
- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16176
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2795

Has anyone could tell me what the problem is and how to fix it? I would really appreciate it.Thanks.

I expect that `saveUser` will have one element in `contactInfos` collection

```
 @Transactional
  public User updateContactInfo(Long id) { // find user from db and add a ContactInfo to it.
    User user = userRepository.findById(id).get();
    ContactInfo contactInfo = new ContactInfo();
    contactInfo.setUser(user);
    user.getContactInfos().add(contactInfo);
    User saveUser = userRepository.save(user);
    System.out.println(saveUser.getContactInfos().size()); //should be one element in collection
    return user;
  }
```

Comment: can you post the rest of the mappings minus the getters and setters?  for example there isnt a uid field in your mapping

Comment: uid field is foreign key

Answer (score 0):

You can probably workaround this bug by initializing the `contactInfos` collection before adding the element to it, as this seems to be related to queued operations not being synchronized properly when lazy loading the collection.
If you can create a [reproducer](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-6/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) against Hibernate 6.2, chances are good that this will be fixed soon.

Comment: I create a reproducer against Hibernate 6.2, and issue is still reproducible.https://github.com/cckevincyh/hibernate-test-case-HHH-16176/blob/main/orm/hibernate-orm-6/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java

Comment: Thanks, we'll take a look as soon as possible.